# Alert message if search query is not more then x characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

First, thanks for taking the time to look at my question. Really. This is my question. I'm making a fancybox search page for a website I'm making. Getting the search results in fancybox all work fine.

But if the visitor just clicks on `search` it returns every item on the site. What I would like is make the form so, that the visitor `has` to at least enter 3 characters before the search does a search. If the visitor doesn't enter 3 or more characters fancybox will give an alert saying `please enter at least 3 or more characters`.

I've looked around stackoverflow and found this code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        input_value = $.trim($('#searchkey').val());
        if(input_value == ''){
           alert('Enter some value');
           return false;  //Does not submit the form 
        }else{
          //perform your code if it should not be empty. 
       }
    });
```

So I placed my code inside the correct place, like so:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
input_value = $.trim($('#str').val());
    if(input_value == ''){
       alert('Enter some value');
       return false;  //Does not submit the form 
    } else {
    $(function() {
      $('#search').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.fancybox({
          width: 600,
          height: 600,
          openEffect: 'fade',
          closeEffect: 'fade',       
            href: 'search-post-results.php',
            type: "ajax",
              ajax: {
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                  value: $('#str').val()
                }
              }
            });
          });
        });
    }
});
```

I'm not getting any syntax errors, but if I reload the page it gives me the correct alert. But thats if there are `no` characters entered. So I've changed this line:

`if(input_value == ''){`

to:

`if(input_value == '2'){`

Figuring that I should set a value. But that does nothing. Does anyone have a similar script/snippet that does the same? Or know why this isn't working?

Here is the HTML (nothing special there):

```
<form id="search">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="s" id="str" placeholder="Search...">
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn form-button btn-default">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Thans again for your time.

Comment: if you want the number of characters, then try `input_value.length < x `

Comment: Change `if(input_value == '2')` to `if(input_value.length <  3)` at the moment you're comparing the _value/content_ of the input and not the _amount/length_ of it's value.

Comment: Hello @Jay-oh , please try my code it will sure helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this , 
Also Please change validation position because if you reload then always alert will show . So you can validate after submit action.

```
 $(function() {
      $('#search').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(input_value.length < 3 ){
          // Show your alert message.
        }else{
         // Here you start Ajax Request.
        }

    });

    });
```

Comment: Yeah, thats what I needed to change in the code, found it my self. Still thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use `length` property.

```
if( input_value.length < 3 ){
   // error message if characters are less than 3
} else {
   // continue the search
}
```

Comment: That did it. I had to modify my own code a bit. But this got me in the right way! Thanks!